# How to wait for an async task to complete that starts in onResume() while the user is allowed to click a button in the meantime that depends on it?

Tags: android, asynchronous, callback, kotlin-coroutines, android-livedata

**Android app programming:**

So let's say I trigger an asynchronous task in the onResume() block of my fragment that has 2 Java callback methods on completion - onSuccess() and onFailure(). Meanwhile, there's a button on the screen that the user can click any time. The catch is, on button click I need to wait for the earlier asynchronous task to complete before executing button click code.

I need to show a progress bar on button click while the asynchronous task completes (if it hasn't completed already), but not sure how to code it such that on button click I am aware that the button has been clicked and also the async task hasn't completed yet and I need to wait for it to complete before proceeding further.

I am thinking I need to use LiveData and/or Kotlin coroutines in this process, but not sure how to proceed with it.

Can anyone please guide me in the right direction on this? I am trying my best to understand asynchronous programming.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't use coroutines, etc. right now then you can implement this easily with just a few booleans and ifs. Assuming all `onSuccess()`, `onFailure()` and `onBtnClick()` are invoked on the main thread, this should do the trick:

```kotlin
private var firstTaskRunning = false
private var scheduledSecondTask = false

fun startFirstTask() {
    firstTaskRunning = true
    // start first task
}

fun onSuccess() {
    onFirstTaskFinished()
}

fun onFailure() {
    onFirstTaskFinished()
}

fun onFirstTaskFinished() {
    firstTaskRunning = false
    
    if (scheduledSecondTask) {
        scheduledSecondTask = false
        hideBtnProgress()
        secondTask()
    }
}

fun onBtnClick() {
    if (firstTaskRunning) {
        scheduledSecondTask = true
        showBtnProgress()
    } else {
        secondTask()
    }
}
```

You should also think about other corner cases like for example: first task was scheduled while it is already running; button is clicked while second task is running, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Define a `lateinit var` at the top of your `Activity`,  `private lateinit var asyncJob: Job`

```
override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    asyncJob = lifecycleScope.launch {
        // Do the work
    }
}

fun onButtonClicked() {
    while (asyncJob.isActive) showProgressIndicator()
    hideProgressIndicator()
    // Handle the button click
}
```

Keep in mind that `lifecycleScope`'s default thread is main, if you want a coroutine to run on a background thread, provide an adequate dispatcher to the `launch(dispatcher) {...}` function.

If you're using a `Fragment` instead of an `Activity` use `viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launch` instead of `lifecycleScope.launch`

`lifecycleScope` is an extension function and can be found in `androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:version`

Comment: Thank you for the solution. I am thinking is there a better solution to the while loop in onButtonClicked() method?